# emphasizing "et al."

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using a `.bst` for the bibliography in my thesis; the `.bst` that I am using, I think, was Chicago style originally. I am also using the `natbib` package. Currently, when I use citation, "et al." appears normally in the text. What should I do to emphasize "et al."?

I am assuming that it is related to the functions of the names in `.bst` file which are: `FUNCTION {format.names}` or `FUNCTION {format.names.ed}` or `FUNCTION {format.full.names}`, and therefore, I tried to put emphasize before "et al." or before "other" in these name's functions but none is working. I also went through the previous questions about the same issue here, nevertheless, I couldn't find an answer.

Please help.

Comment: Which style (.bst file) are you using?

Comment: I think, originally, was Chicago style.

Comment: Hmm... hard to give exact advise if you are not sure about the precise style. You can try replacing the string `" et~al."` with "{\em et~al.}" in a local renamed copy of the .bst file.

Comment: The previous comment didn't help because I have already done that as I said in my question! I don't think the functions have been modified in the style I am using, so you can assume that the style is Chicago. What you would do in this case?

Comment: The file `chicago.bst` dates back to 1992. If this is really the file you're working with, there should be eight [8] instances of the string `" et~al."`. (Note the presence of the tilde.) Replace every one of these instances with `" {\em et~al.}"` as per @GonzaloMedina's earlier suggestion, and save the file under a new name, say, `mymara.bst`. Update the TeX filename database if necessary, and start using the modified bibliography style file.

Comment: I have already replaced them all in the file with {\em et al.}, and I have already done what you suggested up. Nothing has been changed! Is there any other suggestion? Is it something has to do with the "other" in these functions?

Comment: I can confirm that my suggestion (reinforced by @Mico) works if you are really using `chicago.bst`. Can you please upload elsewhere (pastebin, for example)the actual .bst file you're working with?

Comment: I have done the emphasizing. I was just about posting the file on pastebin when I found that I have missed one et al when I was trying all yesterday. I have already got it if not for the missing part, I wondered why it didn't work and so that I post my question. Now I have made sure that the style I am using is definitely Chicago, confirmed by what I have done and what you have suggested. Thanks for both of you Gonzalo and Mico. Sorry for disturbing!

Comment: I think it is important to mention that "et al." should not be italicized if you follow the Chicago style as the manual stipulates: Latin and italics: "et al." is not italicized or underlined (van Leunen, p. 27: "Write it without either underlining or italics."; Chicago Manual of Style 7.56: "Commonly used Latin words and abbreviations should not be italicized. ibid, et al., ca., passim." [and later, 6.44: "Note that 'e.g.' and 'i.e.' are not italicized."]).

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: replace every single "et al." and "et~al." in the `.bst` file with

```
\emph{et al.}
```

Change the name of your `.bst` file. Run LaTeX and BibTeX.

Comment: I've corrected the substitution string: `\em` is *not* a command taking arguments.

Comment: dear egreg, but it was already working with the command \em. what is the difference?

Comment: You wrote `{\em{et al.}}`. 1. `\em` is not a command with arguments; 2. using `\emph{text}` is recommended over `{\em text}` because the former automatically adds the italic correction when necessary.

Comment: Surely `\textit` would be more correct than `\emph`? This is explicitly visual formatting, i.e. our desire is for this text to be in italics, rather than simply wanting it emphasised.