# Formatting et al in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, formatting, citing

This is a follow-up question to [emphasizing "et al."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64149/5764), with the new requirement being specific to [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Consider the following minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[maxcitenames = 2]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}  

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{companion}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

`maxcitenames = 2` introduces "et al." when 3 or more authors are present. How can I format "et al." to suit my needs (*italics*, or **bold**, or ...)?

Comment: See also [How do I get “et al.” to appear in italics when using \textcite or \citeauthor with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40798/35864)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update

With a current version of `biblatex`, you can use bibstring sets. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644877/35864.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
  \DeclareBibstringSet{latin}{andothers,ibidem}%
  \DeclareBibstringSetFormat{latin}{\mkbibemph{#1}}%
}
\UndefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
  \UndeclareBibstringSet{latin}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

It should be enough the redefine the `name:andothers` macro.

```
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\mkandothers]{andothers}}
    {}}
```

The only change to the default is that we have `\bibstring[\mkandothers]{andothers}`, so that the 'andothers' bibstring is wrapped in `\mkandothers`, that can be defined as

```
\newcommand*{\mkandothers}{\mkbibemph}
```

In total

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[maxcitenames = 2]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}  

\newcommand*{\mkandothers}{\mkbibemph}
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\mkandothers]{andothers}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
\citeauthor{companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Goossens et al.]

Comment: Wouldn't t be better if this was done directly instead of having user interaction? biblatex provides fieldformats for nearly everything. renewable delims etc. For a regular user, this is nearly witchcraft.

Comment: @Johannes_B Mhh, yes I am a fan of new options, especially seeing that we have `\mkibid` that works in exactly the same way for 'ibid' already. On the other question I linked to above, Audrey said: 'You can submit feature requests here, though I have my doubts such an option would be incorporated. This is a style issue and the existing style can easily be adapted to meet your needs.'

Answer (score 12):

Probably the simplest way is to define:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  andothers = {\textbf{et al}\adddot}
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[maxcitenames = 2]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  andothers = {\textbf{et al}\adddot}
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{companion}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: In general I would not recommend shoehorning formatting into the localisation files (though I can see that this would make sense if this is a language-specific requirement). But Joseph Wright's `bibilatex-ieee` uses this method: https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/issues/5, https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/commit/fa108ae83adc657373c454687cad953f40201ccb

Comment: @moewe The issue is that it's not necessarily clear if the formatting is part of the style, the language, _etc._ Here, 'et al.' is used in English but one can't be sure that applies to other languages, so the italic formatting (a choice of the publisher for non-English phrases) may or may not apply ...

Comment: @JosephWright Exactly, that is what I meant to hint at with my parenthetical remark. If this is a localisation feature and not a general one, I can see the merits of putting the formatting into the `.lbx` file. And of course it might be hard to tell if it is a general or localisation-dependent feature.