# \citeauthor with et al in italics using BibTex in a given template

Tags: bibtex, formatting, citing, beilstein

As many people I would like to follow the English-language typesetting convention that Latin abbreviations are set in italics (Examples being e.g., i.e. or et al.). While this is easy enough for e.g. and i.e. which I can define as a newcommand, I would like to use `\citeauthor` for a bit more automatisation. However, the et al. produced is not in italics.

Now, I realise there are many similar questions, HOWEVER: most of them answer this issue using `biblatex` or the answer is essentially "make your own `.bst` file" ([BibTeX style with "et al" in italic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/532367/118712)) or even "change the existing `.bst` ([emphasizing "et al."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64149/118712)) The latter being a big No-no.

I am working with a given journal template (more specifically the `beilstein` class available on CTAN) that uses `bibtex` (archaic, I know), so, yes I can define my own commands to a certain extent, but I cannot use customised `.bst` files nor `biblatex` syntax.

Is there an easy way to this or should I rather stick to manually spelling out the author names with a custom et al.-command?

Comment: https://www.beilstein-journals.org/bjnano/authorInstructions says "The Authors should adhere to the ACS Style Guide [...] on matters of [...] references, use of italics and punctuation." The ACS Style Guide says "Do not use italic type for common Latin terms and abbreviations." and explicitly lists "et al." as a common Latin abbreviation. So I think Beilstein want no italics here. This is corroborated by published papers like https://doi.org/10.3762%2Fbjnano.9.98, where all "et al."s are upright.

Comment: Apart from that I don't really see a safe way to do this without changes to the `.bst` file. The only way I could see to do this from the LaTeX side at all would involve capturing and post-processing the author information. But that would require patches to internal macros and additional machinery, something journals are generally not fond of at all.